# Multiple filters on a subform

Tags: ms-access, vba

Trying to apply 2 filters at the same time to a subform.

Want to see records between DATES X and Y, and from BRANCH Z only.

Working fine alone, but can't use both at the same time. I know it's something

Current code:

```
Private Sub Command39_Click()
If IsNull(Me.txtFrom) Or IsNull(Me.txtTo) Then
    MsgBox "Insert date!"
Else
    With Me.frmDailyRevenue.Form
        .Filter = "[DateDbl] BETWEEN " & Me.txtFromDbl & " AND " & Me.txtToDbl & "" And [F5] = " & Me.cboBranch & """
        .FilterOn = True
    End With
  End If 
End Sub
```

This is basically bits of code I got from the web as I'm really new to this.

So, all advice is welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
.Filter = "[DateDbl] BETWEEN #" & Format(Me.txtFromDbl,"mm\/dd\/yyyy") & _
     "# AND #" & Format(Me.txtToDbl,"mm\/dd\/yyyy") & "# And [F5] = '" & Me.cboBranch & "'"
```

I supposed that Me.cboBranch is text. If this field contains code, remove single quotes.

Also I noticed that controls you check and controls you take data from are different (Me.txtFrom and Me.txtFromDbl, Me.txtTo and Me.txtToDbl), check this.

Comment: Changed the line to the following and it returned this message: "Data type mismatch in criteria experession."

.Filter = "[DateDbl] BETWEEN " & Me.txtFromDbl & " AND " & Me.txtToDbl & " And [F5] = '" & Me.cboAgDep & "'"


I don`t use the # because my date is in number (double) format, not mm/dd/yyyy, for diverse reasons.

Comment: So, [DateDbl] contains number. What is in Me.txtFromDbl? I would use then `BETWEEN " & CLng(CDate(Me.txtFrom)) & " AND...` if in txtForm you have date in normal text format. And check data type of table field, which is control source for cboAgDep. If number, remove single quotes.

Comment: Also instead of `CLng(CDate(Me.txtFrom))` you can use `Format(Me.txtFrom,"#")`

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem.

Using BETWEEN and AND for the date range was causing some conflict with the second AND to add the filter for field F5.

So I switched to use >= and <= as follows:

`.Filter = "[DateDbl] >= " & Me.txtFromDbl & " AND [DateDbl] <= " & Me.txtToDbl & " AND [F5] = " & Me.cboBranch & ""`

Just to clarify, for people that might come for this later, you should use # as Sergey pointed out if you have a date field, my date is in double format, so I don`t need to.

Thanks,

Comment: Datevalues should be inclosed within hashes: `#8/18/2016#`